# Where is the idiom configuration for VS "Quick actions and refactoring"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When writing non english comments in Visual Studio 2022, "Quick actions and refactorings" it offers spelling corrections in the english dictionary (EN-US). There is any way to have multiple dictionaries, on different idioms?

I cannot find the options for it, or any documentation on how to setup the dictionary, or if is possible to have multiple idioms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't noticed that I had a spell checker extension installed.
I thought that it was a native feature of VS.

Specifically, I had EWSoftware Visual Studio Spell Checker extensión, whose documentation is [here](https://ewsoftware.github.io/VSSpellChecker/html/027d2fbc-7bfb-4dc3-b4f5-85f95fcf7629.htm).
His settings can be found at VS menu Tools>Spell Checker>Edit Global Configuration>Dictionary Settings

There, is possible to select more dictionaries, and add them, as documented [here](https://ewsoftware.github.io/VSSpellChecker/html/af34b863-6a1c-41ed-bcf2-48a714686519.htm). It does not works until VS is restarted.